# group option in fstab not working

Tags: mount, group, fstab

I'm trying to take advantage of the "group" option for fstab entries and not having any success.  From the `mount` man page:

> Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems. However, when fstab contains the user option on a line, anybody can mount the corresponding system.
>   ...
>   If any user should be able to unmount, then use users instead of user in the fstab line. The owner option is similar to the user option, with the restriction that the user must be the owner of the special file. This may be useful e.g. for /dev/fd if a login script makes the console user owner of this device. **The group option is similar, with the restriction that the user must be member of the group of the special file.**

I'm testing with a loopback mount using a 1GB file /blergh with an ext4 filesystem on it.  That file is owned by root:disk with permissions 664.  I have a mount point /media/blergh owned by root:disk with permissions 775.  I have an fstab entry like so:

`/blergh /media/blergh ext4 loop,rw,noauto,group 0 2`

Running `mount /media/blergh` as `root` works fine.  Running it as `myuser` gives the error: `mount: only root can mount /blergh on /media/blergh`. The output of `/usr/bin/groups` as `myuser` is `myuser disk` so the group membership is there.  If I change `group` to `user` in the options, `myuser` can mount the filesystem.

What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't the `group` option working?

(Note: for reasons I don't want to get into here, I do not want to solve the problem of enabling `myuser` to mount this filesystem by using `sudo`.)

---

**Edit 20-MAY-2013:**

Additional testing with a real block device suggests the problem lies with `loop` rather than `group`.  I created a new 1GB EBS volume attached as /dev/sdg, owned by root:disk, permissions 664.  I created this fstab entry for it:

`/dev/sdg    /media/sdg    ext4 rw,noauto,group 0 0`

Same as before, just no `loop` since it does not apply here.  I created a mount point for this filesystem at /media/blerg, owned by root:disk, permissions 775.  As before `myuser` is a member of the `disk` group.  Using this test setup `mount /media/sdg` as `myuser` works fine, as does `umount /media/sdg`.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the group? If you run `groups myuser` it will display the groups `myuser` is a member of from the groups file. If you run `groups` (no argument) as `myuser` it will show the current groups the process has. If these differ, you will need to log out and in again to get the new groups applied (or use `newgrp(1)`)

Comment: The group membership is absolutely there.  I edited it into /etc/group myself, and the `groups` command confirms it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a very important detail here. From the man page as quoted (and **emphasized**) by you:

> The group option is similar, with the restriction that the user must be member of the **group of the special file**.

Note my **emphasis** on "special file". If you refer to the following explanation about **group** option:

> **group**  Allow an ordinary (i.e., non-root) user to mount the filesystem if one of his groups matches the **group of the device**. This option implies the options nosuid and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line group,dev,suid).

This means that the **device or special file** that you are trying to mount as `myuser` should have the same *group* ownership as that of user `myuser`.

Here's an example:

Let's assume there's a device `/dev/sda5` on a system, which is mounted on `/builds` directory:

```
# ls -l /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Jun 15 21:20 /dev/sda5
# grep sda5 /etc/fstab
/dev/sda5       /builds reiserfs        group,defaults 1 2
```

Also, there are 2 users on this same system: `foo` and `srinidhi`

```
# id foo
uid=1005(foo) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),33(video)
# id srinidhi
uid=1000(srinidhi) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),16(dialout),6(disk),10(wheel)
```

User `srinidhi` (who is part of group `disk`) tries to mount `/builds`:

```
srinidhi@linux:~> mount /builds/
srinidhi@linux:~> echo $?
0
```

Now, let's see what happens when `foo` tries to mount `/builds`:

```
srinidhi@linux:~> su - foo
foo@linux:~> mount /builds/
mount: only root can mount /dev/sda5 on /builds
foo@linux:~>
```

Since `foo` is not part of `disk` group, `mount` fails.

Coming back to your case, you should make sure that group ownership of `/blergh` should either be `myuser` or `disk`. Simply set the correct group ownership and your original `/etc/fstab` entry should start working:

```
# chgrp myuser /blergh
```

Now try running `mount /media/blergh` as `myuser`.

**Note:** Ownership of mount point (here `/media/blergh`) does not affect `mount`.

Comment: I did not miss that.  The user attempting to mount is a member of the "disk" group, which is the owning group of the file.  Further, as I stated in my edit, it appears that the fstab "group" functionality *only works for special files* and not loop mounts.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you mentioned ownership and permissions of `/blergh`.

So I did some digging inside sources of `util-linux` and if I'm reading the sources right, then the "owner" and "group" matches aren't done if the file doesn't start with `/dev/`. So if you first run `losetup loop0 /blergh` and then use `/dev/loop0  /blergh..` in /etc/fstab, everything works as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with the option `user`. Not solved yet.
My approach to solving is to create variants of the situation to see whether they work, and possibly make something emerge.

Is your problem only with that one file `/blergh`  ? Can you reproduce it with another file ? Or with that file located somewhere else, or with different permissions, or with different ownership. (of course, testing depends on how much
control you have over the system).

Can you test the problem with the option `owner` to see whether it works ...  assuming you can reproduce it on another file, or change temporarily ownership ?
What about option `user`.

Is your problem for both mounting and umounting, or for only one of them ? If mounting does not work, you could attempt mounting as `root` and umounting as `myuser`. (in the case of my own problem, mounting works, but umounting does not)

*Side note: I believe this kind of mount is called "loop" in the Linux world, "loopback" having to do with networking devices.*(ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device)

**Added after the first comment and the question editing**

If `owner` does not work either, that means that all ownership mecanisms are affected, since `owner` is easier to check than `group`. Is it the case that `owner` works for real block devices, like `group` does ?

Have you tried specifying explicitly the loop device in the loop option, choosing one that is not used : `...,loop=/dev/loop7,...` ? You might even try to change the ownership or group  of the loop device (though I am not sure how wise or useful it can be). `ls /dev/loop*` gives the available loop devices.

Another possibility is to remove the option `loop` altogether from your `/etc/fstab` entry.  On many systems it is no longer needed, and is done implicitly by mount.  What system are you using, btw ?

Comment: With my loopback test, `user` works perfectly, but `owner` does not work at all.  What I did find though is that my problem with `group` seems confined to `loop` and does not manifest with real block devices.  I will edit my question with further details.

Comment: @Noah Yetter -- did you try my last suggestions added above ?  Did you find a solution ? By the way: I have the soloution to my problem with option `user`  but I do not believe it would help you.